# Android studio shared preferences store to device storage

Tags: java, android

I'm a new android app developer. I was making an app and i would like to store the balance integer using shared preferences but I'm not sure how to do it. I did a lot of googling and I'm still confused. Could anyone please put the shared preferences to store the balance integer in my code? Here's the code.

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int balance = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Hide notification bar
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        //Click counter
        final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.balance_text);
        assert text != null;
        text.setText(balance + " $");
        final ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.click_button);
        assert button != null;
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                balance++;
                text.setText("" + balance + " $");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the below code to get the values from sharedpreferences

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int balance;;
private SharedPreferences preferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Hide notification bar
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    //Click counter
    final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.balance_text);
    assert text != null;
    // to retreuve the values from the shared preference
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    balance = preferences.getInt("balance", 0);
    text.setText(balance + " $");
    final ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.click_button);
    assert button != null;
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            balance++;
            text.setText("" + balance + " $");
        }
    });
}
```

}

Use these lines to save to shared preference. You can use this on your onBackPressed()

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("balance", balance);
        editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: Please import the classes.. import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

Comment: There's just one more thing i need, can you please explain to me how to use onBackPressed() or just give me the code i need to put in. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, i cannot explain how happy this made me, i was googling all day and i could find anything.